# Multiplying columns from different dataframes with different lengths and two conditions in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, multiplication, data-handling

I have two data frames with different lengths. I want to mutate the columns in data frame **df** with the multiplication of **CAP * currency** and **Go * currency** from **df_cur**. This should be done with the **conditions** that **country and Year** must be the same for the two data fames respectively. More specifically,

#df#

| Country | Sector | Year | Cap | Go | Exposion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | A | 2000 | 100 | 200 | 0.2 |
| AUS | B | 2000 | 150 | 200 | 0.3 |
| AUS | C | 2000 | 160 | 160 | 0.25 |
| AUS | A | 2001 | 110 | 200 | 0.25 |
| AUS | B | 2001 | 140 | 190 | 0.4 |
| AUS | C | 2001 | 165 | 155 | 0.2 |
| BEL | A | 2000 | 50 | 150 | 0.1 |
| BEL | B | 2000 | 70 | 160 | 0.15 |
| BEL | C | 2000 | 100 | 200 | 0.2 |
| BEL | A | 2001 | 55 | 160 | 0.15 |
| BEL | B | 2001 | 65 | 140 | 0.1 |
| BEL | C | 2001 | 110 | 190 | 0.3 |

#df_cur#

| country | year | currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | 2000 | 0.58 |
| AUS | 2001 | 0.60 |
| BEL | 2000 | 0.92 |
| BEL | 2001 | 0.95 |

So, I want to transform df like:

#df#

| Country | Sector | Year | Cap | Go | Exposion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | A | 2000 | 100*0.58 | 200*0.58 | 0.2 |
| AUS | B | 2000 | 150*0.58 | 300*0.58 | 0.3 |
| AUS | C | 2000 | 160*0.58 | 160*0.58 | 0.25 |
| AUS | A | 2001 | 110*0.6 | 200*0.6 | 0.25 |
| AUS | B | 2001 | 140*0.6 | 190*0.6 | 0.4 |
| AUS | C | 2001 | 165*0.6 | 155*0.6 | 0.2 |
| BEL | A | 2000 | 50*0.92 | 150*0.92 | 0.1 |
| BEL | B | 2000 | 70*0.92 | 160*0.92 | 0.15 |
| BEL | C | 2000 | 100*0.92 | 200*0.92 | 0.2 |
| BEL | A | 2001 | 55*0.95 | 160*0.95 | 0.15 |
| BEL | B | 2001 | 65*0.95 | 140*0.95 | 0.1 |
| BEL | C | 2001 | 110*0.95 | 190*0.95 | 0.3 |

I reviewed many answers from [Multiplying columns of different size of 2 data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485542/multiplying-columns-of-different-size-of-2-data-frames) but nothing worked for me.

My code sample:

```
Country<-c("AUS","AUS","AUS","AUS","AUS","AUS", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL")
Sector<-c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
Year<-c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001")
Cap<-c(100,150,160,110,140,165,50,70,100,55,65,110)
Go<-c(200,200,160,200,190,155,150,160,200,160,140,190)
Exposion<-c(0.2,0.3,0.25,0.25,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.15,0.1,0.3)
df<-data.frame(Country,Sector,Year,Cap,Go,Exposion)

country<-c("AUS","AUS", "BEL", "BEL")
Year<-c("200","2001","2000","2001")
currency<-c(0.58, 0.6, 0.92, 0.95)
df_cur<-data.frame(country,Year,currency)
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Panagiotis! The easiest is to first combine the two data.frames. Then in the second step you can create new columns with `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(., df_cur) %>%
  mutate(cap2 = Cap * currency) %>%
  mutate(go2 = Go * currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df_cur, c("Cap", "Go") := 
     .(Cap * currency, Go * currency), on = .(Country = country, Year)]
```

-output

```
df
#    Country Sector Year    Cap    Go Exposion
# 1:     AUS      A 2000 100.00 200.0     0.20
# 2:     AUS      B 2000 150.00 200.0     0.30
# 3:     AUS      C 2000 160.00 160.0     0.25
# 4:     AUS      A 2001  66.00 120.0     0.25
# 5:     AUS      B 2001  84.00 114.0     0.40
# 6:     AUS      C 2001  99.00  93.0     0.20
# 7:     BEL      A 2000  46.00 138.0     0.10
# 8:     BEL      B 2000  64.40 147.2     0.15
# 9:     BEL      C 2000  92.00 184.0     0.20
#10:     BEL      A 2001  52.25 152.0     0.15
#11:     BEL      B 2001  61.75 133.0     0.10
#12:     BEL      C 2001 104.50 180.5     0.30
```